# eks- Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

getting this error while executing terraform init for eks service

```
Initializing modules...
Downloading registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws 17.24.0 for eks...
- eks in .terraform/modules/eks
- eks.fargate in .terraform/modules/eks/modules/fargate
- eks.node_groups in .terraform/modules/eks/modules/node_groups

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Reusing previous version of terraform-aws-modules/http from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/helm from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/kubernetes from the dependency lock file
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/kubectl...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/local from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/cloudinit from the dependency lock file
- Installing terraform-aws-modules/http v2.4.1...
- Installed terraform-aws-modules/http v2.4.1 (self-signed, key ID B2C1C0641B6B0EB7)
- Installing hashicorp/aws v4.31.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v4.31.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/helm v2.6.0...
- Installed hashicorp/helm v2.6.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/kubernetes v2.13.1...
- Installed hashicorp/kubernetes v2.13.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/local v2.0.0...
- Installed hashicorp/local v2.0.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/cloudinit v2.2.0...
- Installed hashicorp/cloudinit v2.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/kubectl: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubectl
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on
│ hashicorp/kubectl, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

eks cluster is created. i am having issue with creating eks service.

Comment: The error does not mean much without the code you are using. However, I am pretty sure that the `kubectl` provider does not exist. That is why it would be beneficial to see the `required_providers` part of your code at least.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is likely some Terraform version compatibility error against the .tf files. Check your provider requirement tf.

https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements